# ViewPager - Refresh fragments view on swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hi I want to update the view of viewpager's fragment on swipe (something similar to setOffscreenPageLimit = 0 which doesnt work because minimum offset is 1) but I dont know how. I tried with interface but i get nullpointer exception on parts of my view which visibility I try to set:

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            ((OnRefreshListener) adapter.getItem(position)).onRefresh();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}
    });
```

Implemented interface:

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    if(AddLesson.addNext) {
        addDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        addLesson.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        addWithData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        addWithoutData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        AddLessonDetails addDetails = AddLessonDetails.newInstance(CONTENT[position]);
        return addDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CONTENT.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

What can I do to solve that problem?

Comment: Null pointer means you are trying to use an object you have not initialised. To avoid it, make sure the object you are using is not null.

Comment: Yea I know it but i guess that onCreateView where i initialise parts of my layout isnt called on swipe.

Comment: There is no way to tell what the issue is as you have not specified where the exception is thrown.

Comment: exception is thrown in onRefresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling getItem on your adapter which is returning (I assume) a brand new fragment.

Because you are returning an uninitialised fragment and then immediately calling its `OnRefresh` method which is attempting to manipulate views that have not been created, you get a NPE.

Do not attempt to access views in a fragment until AFTER `OnCreateView` is called.

Comment: so what can i do to call onRefresh after oncreateview

Comment: What do you mean? Just call the method after the views are created not before. You cannot use a view that does not exist.

Comment: How can i call this ((OnRefreshListener) adapter.getItem(position)).onRefresh(); after views are created?

Comment: You can't. As stated, getItem returns a fragment with its views not yet created so you cannot then manipulate views because they do not exist. Just set up your views to the correct default visibility if you want them to have a specific visibility when they are first created.

Comment: Think about it. The visibility of your views will always be the same because it is a brand new fragment. There is no code that can run to alter the visibility of any view. Just set the visibility to whatever you want in the layout file or in the onCreateView method.

Comment: But what if I want to change their visibility after certain requirements are met (after user click a button in one of the fragments the visibility of the rest of fragments must change so when he swaps to the next fragment the view must be updated)

Comment: But your getView method returns A BRAND NEW FRAGMENT every time. You are not updating or retrieving an existing fragment.

Comment: So is there any other way to achieve the effect I want?

Comment: Check this out http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the time you've spent on helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This will affect the changes from one page to another page in view pager.

OnPageChangeListener pagechangelistener =new OnPageChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            Logger.logMessage("Called first");

            pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            indicator.setCurrentItem(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

            Logger.logMessage("Called second");

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            Logger.logMessage("Called third");

        }
    };
    myViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pagechangelistener);
```

Use this in your page adapter.

@Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

```
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```